# adding to an array in json column in Postgres

Tags: sql, json, postgresql

I have a json object column in a Postgres table.
Suppose each record contains the value for this column similar to the below json

```
{"country":"USA","states":["Texas","Alaska"]}
```

How would I create an update statement to add a new state "Virginia" to the state array in that json column.

table name : person-details
column name : location

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[demo:db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_11&fiddle=153c95dd8d9c8e02e5897aef9e1226be)

Using `jsonb_insert()`:

```
UPDATE nations
SET nation = jsonb_insert(nation::jsonb, '{states,0}', '"Virginia"')::json
WHERE nation ->> 'country' = 'USA';
```

If your data type is `json`, then you'll need the casts into type `jsonb` and back (as shown)

Comment: What if I want to add a value from the same json to an array in the same json.

Comment: Can you give an example?

Comment: sample json : {"country":"USA","states":["Texas","Alaska"], "other":"NewYork"}         how would I update the value of states to contain the value present in other as well.

Comment: you want to get "new york" into the array?

Comment: I want to get the string whatever text is present in "other" to be addded to the states array. In this example , "New York"